# use Google Cloud Functions with a registry other than registry.npmjs.org

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently trying to deploy a node.js cloud function using a (private) package from the GitHub package registry (npm.pkg.github.com).

According to the official docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#using_private_modules), using private modules is supported by adding a .npmrc file with an access token, however there is no mention of using custom registries.

The .npmrc which I upload to Cloud Functions alongside the package.json and the rest of the code looks like this:

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/<myorg>
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<mytoken>
```

However, the deployment fails due to:

```
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<mypackage> - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 '<mypackage>' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

So as you can see, the registry definition from the .npmrc seems to be ignored, as it tries to pull the package from npmjs.org, where it does indeed not exist.

Do Google Cloud Functions not support custom registries?

---

Edit: added verbose log output

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm ERR! code E404\nnpm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<redacted> - Not found\nnpm ERR! 404 \nnpm ERR! 404  '<redacted>' is not in the npm registry.\nnpm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)\nnpm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'functions'\nnpm ERR! 404 \nnpm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a\nnpm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-02-12T14_14_22_565Z-debug.log\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno 1\nnpm ERR! @ preinstall: `./install-function-dependencies`\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the @ preinstall script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-02-12T14_14_22_586Z-debug.log\n\nerror: `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "BDE5340F"}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 981, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 307, in Run
    return _Run(args, track=self.ReleaseTrack())
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 263, in _Run
    op, do_every_poll=TryToSetInvokerPermission)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 306, in CatchHTTPErrorRaiseHTTPExceptionFn
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 353, in WaitForFunctionUpdateOperation
    do_every_poll=do_every_poll)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 137, in Wait
    _WaitForOperation(client, request, notice, do_every_poll)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 111, in _WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=SLEEP_MS)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 219, in RetryOnResult
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 70, in _GetOperationStatus
    raise exceptions.FunctionsError(OperationErrorToString(op.error))
FunctionsError: OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm ERR! code E404\nnpm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<redacted> - Not found\nnpm ERR! 404 \nnpm ERR! 404  '<redacted>' is not in the npm registry.\nnpm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)\nnpm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'functions'\nnpm ERR! 404 \nnpm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a\nnpm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-02-12T14_14_22_565Z-debug.log\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno 1\nnpm ERR! @ preinstall: `./install-function-dependencies`\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the @ preinstall script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-02-12T14_14_22_586Z-debug.log\n\nerror: `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "BDE5340F"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do Google Cloud Functions not support custom registries?

Google Cloud Functions should support custom registries.
What version of Nodejs are you using? There were reported some other similar issues: [Runtime doesn't support private npm packages](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131271069) with Nodejs 10.

On the thread it is mentionded that:

> > I would like to inform you that the Cloud Functions engineering team
> >     has rolled out a change to resolve this issue. You may feel free to
> >     try your migration efforts from Node.js 8 to Node.js 10 again. The
> >     roll out addresses the 404 NOT_FOUND issue when trying to install private
> >     packages.

Also I would suggest to test deploying your cloud function using env variables.

```
gcloud functions deploy functionName 
 --region europe-west1 
 --runtime nodejs10 
 --source=SOURCE
 --set-env-vars= NPM_REGISTRY=<your private registry URL>, NPM_SCOPE=<@private-registry-scope>, NPM_CONFIG_EXTRA=auth_token
```

## EDIT

It seems that the issue resurfaced again for Nodejs10 [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36665861)

Comment: I'm using the node10 runtime. Unfortunately, adding the env variables did not make any difference. I'm still seeing the same error while packages are resolved from registry.npmjs.org :|

Comment: I just tried with the node8 runtime, and there it actually works 

Comment: I am happy that it works. If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted for better visibility for the community.

Comment: It seems to be failing for "@google-cloud" repositories now. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon same issue and as far as I understand, private registries (other than npm) are not supported in Google Cloud Functions, as official documentation explicitly [declares](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs):

> Note: Registries other than npm, such as GitHub packages, are not supported in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue with Cloud Functions, however, there seems to be a generalized error currently with npmjs.org, you can check it in forums such as [this one](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8465) in order to see more.

Try this again once the issue in npmjs.org is gone.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: the cloud function deployment should not attempt to resolve anything from registry.npmjs.org, but it does (at least that's what the log says) - so any issues with registry.npmjs.org should not actually be a concern in this case

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the error you are getting? It would also be useful if you added the --verbosity="debug" flag to your deploy command so that we have more information on which step is sending this error

Comment: I added the verbose log to the question but I don't think there is anything helpful in there... GCP should simply not try to resolve stuff from registry.npmjs.org, but it does.